# Matlab: assert(array) vs if (array)

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, assert, boolean-expression

In Matlab (as of 2016a) the conditional
`if (array_of_logicals)` is functionally equivalent to `if (all(array_of_logicals))`. The [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) says: "An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric)."

On the other hand, `assert()` [only accepts](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assert.html) a "Condition to assert, specified as a valid MATLAB expression." Experimentally, this means an `array_of_logicals` should be used as `assert(all(array_of_logicals))`.

What would you say is the reason for the slightly different behavior?

I understand that one reason could be that with `assert()` you want to exclude the interpretation ambiguity of `assert(all(array_of_logicals))` vs `assert(any(array_of_logicals))`,
but the same could be said about `if`.

Edit: In particular, I would like to understand, why this behavior was chosen for `if`.

Comment: This is really just open to speculation, but I would assume that it's because `assert` by nature should be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `assert` within your code, you want to make absolutely certain that a given condition is true and part of that is to remove any ambiguity in the definition of true. By requiring a `logical` scalar, `assert` forces the user to determine exactly what they expect. This also ensures that if for some reason MATLAB wanted to change how they convert arbitrary data to a `logical` scalar, your `assert` calls would remain unaffected.

As far as why `if` doesn't require an explicit `logical` scalar, I'm not sure but it's likely just to ease coding, particularly when MATLAB uses the `double` datatype by default

```
condition = 1

% This will fail since condition is a double not a logical value
assert(condition)

% This won't work if you required explicit logical scalars
if condition
end
```

Comment: I cannot think of myself resorting to this "ease of coding", it just smells nasty. Cf. edit.

Comment: @user66081 I've updated with a small example showing how this "ease of coding" isn't as nasty as you think.

Comment: aha; nota bene: `assert(1);` throws in Matlab.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into it. My guess is the two were developed independently, and the coders involved went with a different design decision. Octave treats `assert` the same way as `if`, which, while I see the point about 'strictness', tbh I still think it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `assert` is to perform execution tests, so it is reasonable to have coded it to expect a true / false input (i.e. a "logical scalar") representing the test outcome, rather than any nonzero array. The `if` can afford to be more general, since it's far more likely to receive matrix comparison expressions rather than execution / validation tests.

However, to be honest, I suspect there's no insightful genius behind the decision. The two probably just happened to be implemented independently and the decision was made based on context.

The `if` behaviour is not new, it has been like this as far back as I can remember. On my 2013a: `The statements are executed if the real part of the expression has all non-zero elements`. Whereas for `assert` it just says: `evaluate EXPRESSION and, if it is false...`

Interestingly, octave did not chose to implement `assert` the same way. In octave, this test will pass: `assert([1,1]==[1,1])`;

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Octave way. The decision process within MathWorks on the Matlab language is very strict (of course... + indirect experience), but this particular decision could be an old one, so you could be right. (Still: why doesn't 1 evaluate to true?..)

Comment: Not sure. It specifically checks for a "logical" scalar, which would make sense from a "test evaluation" point of view. I suppose a numerical test could have inherent precision risks? e.g. you wouldn't want your test to succeed because it evaluated to `0.0000000000000000000000003` :p